# Rendering a show action in the index page - rails

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I currently have a index table with all the subscribers then I have link_to that renders the show page of that individual subscriber. I would really like to render a modal with the show page in front of the index page with the subscribers information. I have to be honest I have never really made a modal before and I'm really struggling figuring this out. I will say I got the start of this modal from W3 and it's cool it's just that you have to click a button in the show page to render the modal but I want it to render before it renders the show page in the index. This may seem like I just want someone to code for me but that is not the case I'm just looking for some help in the right direction. I'm truly in over my head on this one. Here is some code for clarity.

### Controller:

```
    class SubscribersController < ApplicationController
  helper_method :sort_column, :sort_direction

  def index
    @search = Subscriber.search(params[:q])
    @subscriber = @search.result
    @search.build_condition if @search.conditions.empty?
    @search.build_sort if @search.sorts.empty?
  end

  def show
    @subscriber = Subscriber.find_by(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @subscriber = Subscriber.new
  end

  def create
    @subscriber = Subscriber.new(subscriber_params)
    if @subscriber.save
      @subscriber.touch(:subscription_date)
      SubscriberMailer.welcome_subscriber(@subscriber).deliver_now
      flash[:notice] = "Subscriber Has Been Successfully Created"
      redirect_to new_subscriber_path(:subscriber)
    else
      render "new"
    end
  end
```

### CURRENT MODAL:

```
     <html>
<title>W3.CSS</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.css">
<body class="w3-container">

<h2>subsriber</h2>

<button onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block'" class="w3-btn">Open Modal</button>

<div id="id01" class="w3-modal">
  <div class="w3-modal-content">
    <div class="w3-container">
      <span onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" class="w3-closebtn">&times;</span>
      <p><%= @subscriber.first_name %></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Like I said I copied this from the W3 site.

I'm not sure what else to show? I think I may be looking for an ajax thing I'm not sure? any help would be great! Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you could have one hidden modal at the bottom of the page and when a subscriber is clicked, an ajax call is made, the controller fetches the database info, a file with the `js.erb` extension runs, and fills the modal with that subscriber's info.

```
# assets/javascripts/application.js

function subFetch() {
  $('.sub').click(function() {
    $.ajax(
      url: "/subrsciber/" + id,
      type: "GET"
    )
  })
}
```

```
# contollers/subscribers_controller.rb

class SubscribersController
  def show
    @sub = Subscriber.find params[:id]
  end
end
```

This is the jQuery that runs after the controller#action is done running its code

```
# views/subscribers/show.js.erb

$('#modal .body').replacewith("<%= j( render 'subscribers/show') %>")
$(subFetch);
```

You will also need a partial to get the `render 'subscribers/show.js.erb'` to work

```
# views/subscribers/_show.html.erb

<h3><%= @sub.name %></h3>
<p><%= @sub.info %></p>
```

That should point you in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a `show.js.erb` and in that you have to call the modal. 
Pass a remote true in your show link_to as it will call the modal through js. Your link_to will be like this:

`link_to 'show' , subscriber_path(@subscriber) , remote: true`

and the show.js.erb will be :

```
$("#your_global_modal_id").html("<%= j render partial: 'modal' %>");
$("#your_global_modal_id").show();
```

This will do the job.